# CSS multiple values in Class attribute

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the process of learning bootstrap and something that's new to me (i last programmed web forms 2.0 on the web side) is the class attributes with multiple values

for example `<div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse">`

I've tried googling a few phrases to look for an explanation "multiple values in class attribute, bootstrap" etc. and i've followed the links when i was typing up this question but i can't seem to find a good explanation of what it is exactly. is it inheritance, some kind of cascade manipulation or one class with spaces in its name?

Comment: You can assign multiple classes to any element and you separate each one by a space. So in your example, the div has three classes.

Comment: ok thats what i thought. Then i'd guess to overwrite say color, you'd find the one(s) that set that property and target those down the cascade somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only different classes, that's all. In your example, that div will have the class navbar, which has specific styles for a default navigation bar, it also has the class navbar-collapse, which is used in bootstrap to tell an element that it has to collapse at an specific width, allowing it to look like a different collapsed dropdown menu. Bootstrap has a lot of these classes and for you to known them all I suggest you to take a closer look at the doc in the website which explains in more details each specific class.

Answer (score 2):

In the DOM, an object can have multiple classes attached.  These classes are completely independent of one another, and are usually used in CSS to get greater specificity when referring to an actual DOM node.

In your example, the div is `navbar`, `navbar-collapse` and `collapse`.  This allows code elsewhere to add and remove classes to change the appearance of the DOM node.

Eg: If I were to remove `navbar-collapse` and `collapse` from this `div`s classes, I would expect the navbar to no longer be collapsed - but still retain all the `navbar` styling.